# How to set first value of plus button click as default value to save in my TextView?

Tags: android, textview, buttonclick

The problem is to display the first value as default value in TextView for the + Button click which increases the value. These are the variables in which

mInteger` is -

```
int minteger =0;
int count=0;
```

These are 2 functions which is increaseInteger(View view) function is for Plus button click and `decreaseInteger(View view)` function is for Decrease button click. Below is the code for plus and minus button clicks

```
public void increaseInteger(View view) {
            minteger++; //for increasing value
            display(minteger);
        }public void decreaseInteger(View view) {
            if(minteger>0)
            {
                minteger--;  //for decreasing value
                display(minteger);
            }
        }
```

Below code is to show the changes in TextViews according to the **mInteger** which is changed by button clicks. The display() function uses button click integer but how to set the default value in TextView as 1 and other values changes accordingly as default values when the activity opens.

```
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView displayInteger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantityPerTeam);
        displayInteger.setText("" + number);
        int total=count*minteger;
        quantityTeam.setText((String.valueOf(total))+" "+"Images@$2.49/print");
        float total1=total;
        total1= (float) (total*2.49);
        totalprint.setText("Total: $" +(String.valueOf(total1)));
    }
```

How to set the default value as 1 of **mInteger** when the activity first loads? and show the calculated values accordingly.

Comment: Not sure what is problem here.. you can define value as `int minteger =1;` or you can set its value inside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

you can set Text of the **displayInteger** When the Activity is loaded
Inside the onCreate method add the following

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int minteger =1;
        TextView displayInteger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantityPerTeam);
        displayInteger.setText("" + minteger);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file,set text to '1' in TextView in android by default.
Try this

```
int count=1;
increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               ++count;
            }
        });
displayInteger.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```